# Need data from multple rows on single output row. Subquery?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, self-join

I'm fairly new with working with MySQL so please excuse the vague title, I wasn't sure how to ask this question or if it truly does require a subquery.
Edit: Thanks @O. Jones for revising the title.

I have a table of employees, which is structured like so:

```
CREATE TABLE Employees (
  employeeNumber INTEGER NOT NULL,
  lastName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  firstName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  extension VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  email VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  officeCode INTEGER NOT NULL,
  reportsTo INTEGER NULL,
  jobTitle VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (employeeNumber),
  FOREIGN KEY (officeCode) references Offices(officeCode)
)ENGINE=innodb;
```

I am trying to come up with a query that will list 3 pieces of data. The `employeeNumber`, the employee's name tied to that number (`CONCAT(e.firstName, ' ', e.lastName)`), and the employee's `Manager`, which we see as `reportsTo`. My issue is, `reportsTo` is just another `employeeNumber`, so to turn that into an actual name I believe we need a sub-query.

Here is an example of what the data set will look like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MR5Hs.png

Can someone tell me if a sub-query is actually necessary or if there's a better way to do this, and possibly point me in the right direction to complete my query? This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT
    e.employeeNumber as 'Employee Number',
    CONCAT(e.firstName, ' ', e.lastName) as 'Employee',
    # as 'Manager'
FROM Employees e;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Join

```
 SELECT e.employeeNumber as 'EmployeeNumber', CONCAT(e.firstName, ' ', e.lastName) as 'Employee', CONCAT(m.firstName, ' ', m.lastName) as 'Manager'
  FROM Employees e
  LEFT JOIN Employees m ON m.employeeNumber = e.reportsTo ;
```

Comment: Good answer. This is called a *self-join* operation. And, if the result should include persons without managers (the boss?) it should be a `LEFT JOIN` .

Comment: Ah, I was overthinking this entirely. I've never joined a table to its self before so I didn't even think of trying this. This makes sense though and completes the task I was working on. Thank you very much.

Comment: I remember my *aha* moment when I figured out self joins. It's a very useful query pattern.

Comment: @O.Jones oh! yes . If the Manager field is not mandatory , this query wont show the employees with no Manager. Then it should be Left Join.  I'll update the answer

Answer (score 2):

You can use a subquery but using a [join](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-join/) would be simpler.

```
SELECT
    e.employeeNumber as 'Employee Number',
    CONCAT(e.firstName, ' ', e.lastName) as 'Employee',
    e.reportsTo as 'Manager Number',
    CONCAT(m.firstName, ' ', m.lastName) as 'Manager'
FROM Employees e LEFT JOIN Employees m
ON e.reportsTo=m.employeeNumber;
```

A left join is used in this case as there might be some employees without any manager to whom they report to, in which case we would want to fetch them too.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm now discovering self joins are a thing!